# How to disable UIScrollView's animation of shaking when paging is done?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating a ebook app and using the UIScrollView to show each of the pages. The paging mode of the UIScrollView just works fine. But I noticed a behaviour of UIScrollView's paging that I don't want. for example, user swipe the screen from right to left, and page will be translated from right to left correspondingly, when content's edge hit the edge of screen, UIScrollView will make it go little further and bounce back. so, my question is how to disable this default behaviour of UIScrollView?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation refers to that as [bounce](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces). Basically you would do this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Related properties are:

- [alwaysBounceVertical](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/alwaysBounceVertical)
- [alwaysBounceHorizontal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/alwaysBounceHorizontal)